# Regex pattern number question for phone number

Tags: javascript, regex

What is the regex pattern for:

- Cannot start with a '0', '1' or '+'
- Only numbers are allowed
- Must be to be 10 digits long

I tried `/^[1-9][x-1][x-+]{+10}$/` but it's showing me an error.

Comment: https://regexper.com/#%2F%5E%5B1-9%5D%5Bx-1%5D%5Bx-%2B%5D%7B%2B10%7D%24%2F .... [x-1] <--- range of x to 1?

Comment: `/^[2-9]\d{9}$/`: The first character is in the range `2` to `9` followed by 9 digits.

Comment: If it can not start with a `+`, can it start with a `-`?

Comment: "number" and "digit" are two different concepts. Can be important in the formulation of a question.

Comment: actually x-1, I just saw somewhere, I'm not quite sure what is it for.

Comment: But I just need this pattern: cannot start with a '0', '1' or '+', only number and has to be 10

Comment: actually I just need number, not digit

Comment: @Thefourthbird Just full number and no - to start with

Answer (score 2):

```
let reg = /^[2-9]\d{9}$/g;

console.log(reg.test('9123456789'))
```

Comment: Is this for: cannot start with a '0', '1' or '+', only number and has to be 10?

Comment: How to see the condition with: Cannot start  '0', '1' or '+'

Comment: Still wrong https://regexper.com/#%2F%5E%5B2%2C9%5D%5Cd%7B9%7D%24%2Fg

Comment: @epascarello fixed the typo

Answer (score 1):

```
var str=prompt();
if(/^[^+01]\d{9}$/i.test(str))
    alert("true");
else
    alert("false");
```

Comment: This is matching `X123456789`

Answer (score 0):

**RegEx 1:** `/^(?![0][1][+])[2-9]([0-9]){9}$/`

**RegEx 1 explanation:**

`(?![0][1][+])` Cannot start with a '0', '1' or '+' [ Negative lookahead ]

`[2-9]` Only numbers are allowed [ So the first digit would be one of 2-9 and not 0 or 1 or + ]

`([0-9]){9}` Must be to be 10 digits long [ The remaining {9} digits can be any number between 0 to 9 ]

**RegEx 2:** `/^[2-9]([0-9]){9}$/`

**RegEx 2 explanation:**

`[2-9]` Cannot start with a '0', '1' or '+' and Only numbers are allowed. So the first digit can be only a number between 2-9

`([0-9]){9}` Must be to be 10 digits long [ The remaining {9} digits can be any number between 0 to 9 ]

**RegEx 3:** `/^[2-9]\d{9}$/`

**RegEx 3 explanation:**

`[0-9]` can be represented as `\d`. So changing it in RegEx 2, we will get `/^[2-9]\d{9}$/`, as already mentioned in the other answer

For the first character, it is not sufficient to confirm the non-existence of 0,1 and + , it should be verified to be a number as well.

Comment: In your 1rst regex, the negative lookahead is useless because the first character class `[2-9]` doesn't match any of `0`, `1` or `+`. Moreover it says that the string cannot begin with the **three characters** `01+`